# how to get an attribute from an element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, checkbox, key-value

here is my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/ZXWtZ/)

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="test">
    <legend>Radio buttons, vertical controlgroup:</legend>
    <input class="status" type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked">
    <label for="radio-choice-1">Cat</label>
    <input class="status" type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2">
    <label for="radio-choice-2">Dog</label>
    <input class="status" type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3">
    <label for="radio-choice-3">Hamster</label>
    <input class="status" type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-4" value="choice-4">
    <label for="radio-choice-4">Lizard</label>
</fieldset>

$('.status').on("click", function () {
    var inputs = $('#test').find('input');
    $.each(inputs, function (i, v) {
        console.log(v);
    });
});
```

i would like to get the `id` and `val()` of all radio buttons, something like:

```
[{
    id: id1,
    value: value1
} {
    id: id2,
    value: value2
}]
...
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the attribute of an element you can use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) like `$(el).attr('class')`.

But to get the desired output in the above case, you can use

```
$('.status').on("click", function () {
    var array = $('#test').find('input').map(function(idx, el){
        return {id: el.id, value: el.value}
    }).get();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2r6TX/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.status').on("click", function () {

var radioid = $(this).attr('id'); //gets the attribute ID of the clicked `.status`
    radioval = $(this).val(); //gets the value of of the clicked `.status`
alert('ID = ' + radioid + ' and VALUE = ' + radioval); //see the magic


var inputs = $('#test').find('input');
$.each(inputs, function (i, v) {
    console.log(v);
});
```

});

Use jquery [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the attribute ID (and other attributes) and [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of the radio button

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXWtZ/1/)